# Magento 2 trying to get the product sizes off from the category page

Tags: magento2, category

I'm using magento 2 , and I'm trying to get rid off the product sizes from the catalog page , I only want the size on the product page.. I've tryed to edit Stores -> (Attributes) Product -> dress_size -> Storefront properties -> Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront set to NO , I save the attribute , clear the cache , but when I come back , Catalog Pages on Storefront is set back to YES.. Does anyone had this issue before ?

Comment: Did you try to reindex ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **No** in `Use in Layered Navigation` field.(if you want not display inside layered navigation).

other option is,
**Used for Sorting in Product Listing set to No**

you just have to reindex command,

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

clear cache and remove browser cache.

Comment: Did also this , still coming out with YES , after reindex and cleared the cache..

Comment: i have updated my answer plz check.

Comment: But if I do like that , it dissapear from the side bar , but is still under the product , the thing is I want to keep it as filter on the side bar , and get rid of it only under the product..